# Create a function in t-SQL which will automatically select source and target tables and update values in specific columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, suppose [dbo].[Anonymised_Data], which contains information about the target table in which certain values need to be modified. The column names are also specified in the table.
´

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
| Target_table |  Column_Name | Original_Value | Masked_Value  |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
| Table 1      | 0RT01        |  Dhaka         | City 1        |
| Table 1      | NAME1        |  P&G           | Vendor 1      |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to create a function which will change the values in these columns of the target table from original value to masked value. I also want the function to be able to switch back the masked value to original value.

So the result would look like, for example:
Previously

```
Table 1
+-------------------+
| ORT01 | Client    | 
+-------------------+
| Dhaka |     A     |
+-------------------+
```

And after running the function it will look like:

```
Table 1
+-------------------+
| ORT01  | Client    | 
+-------------------+
| City 1 |     A     |
+-------------------+
```

That is, all the other values in target table remain the same. 
I also want the option to switch back to the original values.

I understand this can be accomplised with more temporary tables, but [dbo].[Anonymised_Data] will contain reference to a large number of tables and so updating each one by one would be tedious.

If anyone could suggest a solution, would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i can think to do this is by using dynamically generated SQL statements

```
DECLARE @rollBack BIT = 0 --SET TO 1 TO ROLLBACK TO UNMASKED VALUES


DECLARE @updateStatements TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,UpdateStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

;with statements
AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,QUOTENAME(Column_Name) + ' = ''' + CASE @rollBack WHEN 1 THEN Original_Value ELSE Masked_Value END + '''' as SetStatement
    ,'WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(Column_Name) + ' = ''' + CASE @rollBack WHEN 1 THEN Masked_Value ELSE Original_Value END + '''' as WhereClause
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Target_Table, Column_Name) as PID
    FROM Anonymised_Data
)


INSERT INTO @updateStatements
(
    UpdateStatement
)
SELECT
'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(Target_Table) + ' SET ' + SetStatement + ' ' + WhereClause as UpdateStatement
FROM statements


DECLARE @curID INT = 1
DECLARE @maxID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @updateStatements)


WHILE (@curID <= @maxID)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @curStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
    SELECT @curStatement = UpdateStatement
    FROM @updateStatements
    WHERE ID = @curID

    PRINT @curStatement
    EXEC (@curStatement)

    SET @curID += 1
END
```